# Flexbox layout with flexible image gallery and scrollbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar, image-gallery

I want to include an image gallery with scrollbar into a flexbox layout, so when the browser page size changes, the gallery should scale too by the flex-grow index, so that all images in the gallery are still accessible via the scrollbar. Therefore, I do not want to use absolute units. However, I have tried multiple approaches suggested in several forums and websites, but I still can not get the gallery working by including it in my flexbox layout.
Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion.

**Example1: This is the image gallery behaviour I want to achieve when the browser page size becomes smaller than the shown images:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: dimgray;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .gallery {
                flex: 1 1 50%;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: scroll;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Desired behaviour-->
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile1">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile2">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile3">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile5">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile6">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile7">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile8">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile9">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile10">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile11">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile12">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile13">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Tile14">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Example2: This is my flexbox layout wherein I want to integrate the image gallery:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: dimgray;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                height: 100%;
            }
            /************************/
            .column {
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: column nowrap;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .column:nth-child(1) {
                flex: 4 0 40%;
            }
            .column:nth-child(2) {
                flex: 3 0 30%;
            }
            /************************/
            .row {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
            }
            .row:nth-child(1) {
                flex: 1;
            }
            /************************/
            .sub-row {
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                padding: 5px 0;
                color: white;
            }
            .sub-row:last-child {
                border-bottom: none;
            }
            /************************/
            #row-middle-col-left1,
            #row-middle-col-left2 {
                flex-grow: 4;
            }
            #row-middle-col-right1 {
                flex-grow: 10;
            }
            #row-middle-col-right2 {
                /*max-width: 800px;*/
            }
            /************************/
            .gallery {
                flex: 1 1 50%;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                min-width: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Not working like expected-->               
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="row-middle">
                <div class="column" id="row-middle-col-middle">
                    <div class="sub-row" id="row-middle-col-left1">M1</div>
                    <div class="sub-row" id="row-middle-col-left2">M2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="column" id="row-middle-col-right">
                    <div class="sub-row" id="row-middle-col-right1">R1</div>
                    <div class="sub-row" id="row-middle-col-right2">R2
                        <div class="gallery">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image1">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image2">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image3">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image4">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image5">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image6">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image7">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image8">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image9">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image10">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image11">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image12">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image13">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image14">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone how might be interested in the solution that i finally found:
I gave the gallery a fixed size which i then subtracted from the flex-basis:

```
#row-middle-col-right2 {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex: 1 1 (10% - 500px);
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    width: 500px;
}
```

And the complete code goes as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: dimgray;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            .container {
                display: inline-flex;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .column {
                display: inline-flex;
                flex-flow: column nowrap;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .column:nth-child(1) {
                flex: 2 2 20%;
            }
            .column:nth-child(2) {
                flex: 3 3 30%;
            }
            .row {
                display: inline-flex;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
            }
            .row:nth-child(1) {
                flex: 1 1 100%;
            }
            .sub-row {
                display: inline-flex;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            }
            .sub-row:last-child {
                border-bottom: none;
            }
            #row-middle-col-left1,
            #row-middle-col-left2 {
                display: flex;
                flex: 2 2 20%;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
            }
            #row-middle-col-right1 {
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
                flex: 6 6 60%;
            }
            #row-middle-col-right2 {
                display: inline-flex;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
                flex: 1 1 (10% - 500px);
                overflow-x: scroll;
            }
            .gallery {
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
                width: 500px;
            }

            .gallery img {
                white-space: nowrap;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Not working like expected-->               
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="row-middle">
                <div class="column" id="row-middle-col-middle">
                    <div class="sub-row" id="row-middle-col-left1">M1</div>
                    <div class="sub-row" id="row-middle-col-left2">M2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="column" id="row-middle-col-right">
                    <div class="sub-row" id="row-middle-col-right1">R1</div>
                    <div class="sub-row" id="row-middle-col-right2">R2
                        <div class="gallery">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image1">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image2">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image3">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image4">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image5">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image6">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image7">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image8">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image9">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image10">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image11">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image12">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image13">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="Image14">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```